# Find closed form of $a_{n+1} = 4a_n - 2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

Is there a easy way to find the recurrence for $a_{n+1} = 4a_n - 2$, with $a_1 = 2$?

I was learning about finding the closed form of Fibonacci-styled recurrences like $a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} - 3a_{n}$ or something, and then this problem appeared. The textbook did a ton of rearranging to cancel out the $-2$ term and get it into the form of a Fibonacci-styled recurrence. I'm wondering if there is a easier way.

Comment: Find s a solution to $a = 4a -2$. Find the general solution to $a_{n+1} = 4 a_n$. Add and pick the initial condition so $a_1 = 2$ is satisfied.

Comment: If we set $b_n=a_n+k$, the recurrence becomes 
$$ b_{n+1}-k = 4b_n-4k-2, $$
so by conveniently choosing $k=-\frac{2}{3}$ we get  $b_{1}=\frac{4}{3}$, $b_n=\frac{4^n}{3}$ and $a_n=\frac{4^n+2}{3}$.

Comment: The idea in the 2 comments above is that if we can find a constant $s$ such that $s=4s-2,$ then by letting  $a_n=b_n+s,$ we have $b_{n+1}=4b_n.$

Comment: Did the textbook say $a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-2$ and $a_{n+1}=4a_n-2$, so $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=4a_{n+1}-4a_n$, so $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-4a_n$?   That doesn't seem so difficult

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
a_2 &= 4a_1 - 2\\
a_3 &= 4(4a_1-2)-2 = 4^2a_1 - 4\cdot 2 - 2\\
a_4 &= 4(4^2a_1 - 4\cdot 2 - 2) - 2 = 4^3a_1 - 4^2\cdot 2 - 4\cdot 2 - 2.
\end{align*}
This leads to the conjecture
$$
a_n = 4^{n-1}a_1 - 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}4^k = 4^{n-1}a_1 - 2\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{4-1} = 4^{n-1}(a_1-\tfrac 23) + \tfrac 23.
$$
It is easily checked that this sequence satisfies the iteration rule, hence it's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $-2=2/3-4\times2/3$. Therefore,
$$a_{n+1}-\frac{2}{3}=4\left(a_n-\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore,
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : a_{n}-\frac{2}{3}=4^{n-1}\left(a_1-\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
which can be easily proven using induction.